# How to run docker services with an application account?

Tags: windows, docker, hyper-v, windows-service

How do I change the windows services account for docker?

The Windows services are `Docker Desktop Service` and `docker`.

When I set then to use an application account, it returns the following error:

```
Unable to launch process: 1314
   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Core\pipe\NamedPipeClient.cs:line 36
   at Docker.Actions.DoStart(SynchronizationContext syncCtx, Boolean showWelcomeWindow, Boolean executeAfterStartCleanup) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 92
   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<Start>b__0() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Windows\Actions.cs:line 74
   at Docker.WPF.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.<.ctor>b__1() in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.WPF\TaskQueue.cs:line 59
```

I also tried to temporarily give administrative permissions to the account with no success.

Update Log file:

```
[17:26:35.527][GUI            ][Info   ] Starting...
[17:26:35.786][ComponentVersions][Info   ] Edition community
[17:26:35.792][GUI            ][Error  ] An instance is already running. Exiting.
[17:26:38.921][HyperV         ][Info   ] Shutdown VM ...
[17:26:38.945][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM MobyLinuxVM is stopped
[17:26:38.945][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [stop] took 00:00:20.4717348 to run
[17:26:38.945][OptimizeDisk   ][Info   ] Optimize
[17:26:38.945][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...
[17:26:40.565][Moby           ][Info   ] Stop
[17:26:40.576][HyperV         ][Info   ] Create
[17:26:40.576][PowerMode      ][Info   ] Start
[17:26:40.576][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] Installing GUIDs...
[17:26:40.576][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Create True -VhdPathOverride  -VhdSize 64000000000 -SwitchSubnetAddress 10.0.75.0 -SwitchSubnetMaskSize 24 -CPUs 2 -Memory 2048 -IsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\docker-for-win.iso
[17:26:40.576][Firewall       ][Info   ] Removing all existing rules...
[17:26:40.577][HyperVGuids    ][Info   ] GUIDs installed
[17:26:40.628][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 17:26:40.628
[17:26:40.921][Firewall       ][Info   ] All existing rules are removed.
[17:26:40.921][Firewall       ][Info   ] Opening ports for C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\com.docker.proxy.exe...
[17:26:40.934][Firewall       ][Info   ] Opening ports for SMB...
[17:26:40.945][HyperV         ][Info   ] Modules loaded at 17:26:40.945
[17:26:40.947][Firewall       ][Info   ] Ports are opened
[17:26:41.572][HyperV         ][Info   ] Using existing Switch: DockerNAT
[17:26:45.905][HyperV         ][Info   ] Using existing Switch IP address
[17:26:45.934][HyperV         ][Info   ] Setting CPUs to 2 and Memory to 2048 MB
[17:26:47.543][HyperV         ][Info   ] Connect Internal Switch DockerNAT
[17:26:47.875][HyperV         ][Info   ] Remove existing DVDs
[17:26:50.030][HyperV         ][Info   ] Attach DVD C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\docker-for-win.iso
[17:26:50.933][HyperV         ][Info   ] Disabled Guest Service Interface
[17:26:50.955][HyperV         ][Info   ] Enabled Heartbeat
[17:26:50.972][HyperV         ][Info   ] Disabled Key-Value Pair Exchange
[17:26:50.993][HyperV         ][Info   ] Enabled Shutdown
[17:26:51.009][HyperV         ][Info   ] Enabled Time Synchronization
[17:26:51.024][HyperV         ][Info   ] Disabled VSS
[17:26:51.136][HyperV         ][Info   ] VM created.
[17:26:51.136][HyperV         ][Debug  ] [create] took 00:00:10.5592691 to run
[17:26:51.136][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script '(Hyper-V\Get-VM MobyLinuxVM).Id.Guid'...
[17:26:51.150][IsoConfig      ][Info   ] Generating CA Cert Bundle
[17:26:51.176][IsoConfig      ][Info   ] CA Cert Bundle Generated
[17:26:51.796][Moby           ][Info   ] Connecting...
[17:26:51.797][Moby           ][Error  ] Failed to read Moby's logs: The operation has timed out.
[17:26:51.797][HyperV         ][Info   ] Start
[17:26:51.797][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script with parameters: -Start True -IsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\docker-for-win.iso -confIsoFile C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\tmp-d4w\config.iso -DockerIsoFile C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\docker.iso -VhdPathOverride 
[17:26:51.857][HyperV         ][Info   ] Script started at 17:26:51.857
[17:26:51.975][HyperV         ][Info   ] Modules loaded at 17:26:51.975
[17:26:51.979][HyperV         ][Info   ] Starting VM MobyLinuxVM...
[17:26:52.070][HyperV         ][Info   ] Remove existing DVDs
[17:26:52.447][NamedPipeServer][Error  ] Unable to execute Start: Unable to launch process: 1314    at Docker.Win32Helpers.NativeImpersonatedProcess.Start(NativeImpersonatedProcess* , basic_string<wchar_t\,std::char_traits<wchar_t>\,std::allocator<wchar_t> >* watchguardPath) in c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\buildtools\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\xstring:line 1825
   at Docker.Win32Helpers.ImpersonatedProcess.Start(String watchguardPath) in c:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\docker.win32helpers\impersonatedprocess.cpp:line 250
   at Docker.Backend.Processes.ExternalProcess.StartImpersonatedProcess(String fileName, String arguments, String currentDirectory, IDictionary`2 envVariables, WindowsIdentityRecorder identity, CancellationToken stopToken) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\Processes\ExternalProcess.cs:line 66
   at Docker.Backend.Processes.ExternalProcess.Start(String arguments, String currentDirectory, IDictionary`2 envVariables, WindowsIdentityRecorder identity) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\Processes\ExternalProcess.cs:line 52
   at Docker.Backend.Processes.VpnKit.Start(Settings settings, String vmId) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\Processes\VpnKit.cs:line 45
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.DoStart(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 248
   at Docker.Backend.ContainerEngine.Linux.Start(Settings settings, String daemonOptions) in C:\workspaces\stable-18.09.x\src\github.com\docker\pinata\win\src\Docker.Backend\ContainerEngine\Linux.cs:line 117
[17:26:52.593][NamedPipeClient][Error  ] Unable to send Start: Unable to launch process: 1314
[17:26:52.594][Notifications  ][Error  ] Unable to launch process: 1314
```

Comment: Is that the complete message? It looks like something important is missing, such as an error message.

Comment: No, it is just that. I know it is an error accessing the pipeline but i am not sure. I added part of the log file.