# How to configure proxy credentials for docker in windows?

Tags: docker

Setting up a proxy manually doesn't work on my enterprise network. 
When running the docker login it returns the following error message:

```
Error response from daemon: Get https://a/v2/: Proxy Authentication Required ( ... requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
```

I am running the docker instance on Windows 10.

I have tried the following 2 things for debugging:

- Passing the credentials in the URL, but the proxy doesn't seem to allow basic authentication or if it does it will not accept the credentials in the parameters.
- Changing the docker service account, as posted [here](https://serverfault.com/q/976178/255995), but that breaks the docker installation. Commands sent from the PowerShell always return an error when accessing the pipe.

I am out of options. Is there another way to solve this?

If I understand the system correctly, I need some way to pass the credentials to the proxy, because the proxy is requiring it this way. Also, it can't get the credentials from a service running with a local service account.

Answer (score 7):

The documentation at this point in time is not very clear.

Here is what worked out for me on:

```
- Docker 19.03.5, build 633a0ea 
- windows 10 Enterprise platform
```

1) Go to **Docker Desktop > Settings > Proxies**

2) Set **Manual proxy configuration**

3) **Set your proxy and credentials** at Web server and Secure Web server

- create your proxy url and credentials in this format:  domain\username:password@proxy-url.com:port
- remove special characters from domain\username:password at https://www.url-encode-decode.com/
- paste the url in the inputs for Web Server and Secure Web Server

4 - **Add the desired exceptions** to your proxy

Comment: can we add (somehow) the proxy credentials without having the password in plaintext?

Comment: Just to clarify, the username and password need to be URL encoded separately, so e.g. the HTTP setting will look something like `http://{urlencodeusername}:{urlencodedpassword}@proxy.mycompany.com:8080`. And don't paste your password into a random website!